# How to stop a thread which is blocking on a named pipe in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pipe, named-pipes, blocking

I have a class which subclasses `threading.Thread`. It's sole responsibility is putting messages read from a UNIX named pipe to a `queue.Queue` object (so that other threads can process these values later).

Example code:

```
class PipeReaderThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, results_queue, pipe_path):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop_event = Event()
        self._results_queue = results_queue
        self._pipe_path = pipe_path

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            with open(self._pipe_path, 'r') as pipe:
                message = pipe.read()
            self._results_queue.put(message, block=True)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()
```

As you can see I wanted to use a `threading.Event` object to stop the loop, but since the `open()` or `read()` calls on the named pipe will block (until someone opens the pipe for writing / writes to it then closes it), the thread never has the chance to stop.

I didn't want to use nonblocking mode for the named pipe, as the blocking is actually *what I want* in a sense that I want to wait for someone to open and write to the pipe.

With sockets I'd try something like setting a timeout flag on the socket, but I couldn't find any way of doing this for named pipes.
I've also considered just killing the thread in cold blood without giving it a chance to stop gracefully, but this doesn't really feel like something I should be doing, and I don't even know if Python provides any way of doing this.

How should I stop this thread properly, so that I could call `join()` on it afterwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classic way to do this is to have unnamed pipe that signals closing and to use `select` to know which one is to be used.

`select` will block until one of descriptors is ready for read and then you can use `os.read` which will not block in this case.

Code for demonstration (doesn't handle errors, might leak descriptors):

```
class PipeReaderThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, results_queue, pipe_path):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop_pipe_r, self._stop_pipe_w = os.pipe()
        self._results_queue = results_queue
        self._pipe = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY) # use file descriptors directly to read file in parts
        self._buffer = b''

    def run(self):
        while True:
            result = select.select([self._stop_pipe_r, self._pipe], [], [])
            if self._stop_pipe_r in result[0]:
                os.close(self._stop_pipe_r)
                os.close(self._stop_pipe_w)
                os.close(self._pipe)
                return
            self._buffer += os.read(self._pipe, 4096) # select above guarantees read is noblocking
            self._extract_messages_from_buffer() # left as an exercise

    def stop(self):
        os.write(self._stop_pipe_w, b'c')
```

Comment: Should've thought of that. I like that this approach is perfectly in line with Unix philosophy. Thank you.